# cannot get request from JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

I have auto complete input field, so I have done a function to retrieve data based on user request. I have tested the function with webform and it works fine, but when I tried to use api and send request to controller, the controller does not receive any request from JQuery?

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#auto").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "api/Employee/GetRe",
                    data: "{'term':'" + $("#auto").val() + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response(data.d);
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert("Error");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

controller:

```
[HttpGet]
    public string GetRe(string term) {

        var re = repository.GetCategory(term);

        return re.First();

    }
```

function:

```
 [WebMethod]
    public  string[] GetCategory(string term)
    {
        List<string> retCategory = new List<string>();
        connection();

        string query = string.Format("select FirstName from Employee where FirstName Like '%{0}%'", term);
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                retCategory.Add(reader.GetString(0));
            }
        }
        con.Close();

        return retCategory.ToArray();
    }

    }
```

and it shows this error

> "No action was found on the controller 'Employee' that matches the
>   request ."}

Answer (score 0):

You are formatting your JSON object as a string.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#auto").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "api/Employee/GetRe",
                    data: {'term': $("#auto").val()},
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response(data.d);
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert("Error");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
```